# Variadic append function (append any number of lists together)

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket, variadic-functions

I'm trying to implement the scheme procedure *append* myself. The simplest version is to append 2 lists together is quite easy and can be done with:

```
 (define (append lis1 lis2)
                  (if (null? lis1) 
                    lis2
                    (cons (car lis1)
                          (append (cdr lis1) lis2))))
```

The trouble starts when you want to append **any** number of lists. For 0 lists and 1 lists the the idea is simple, but im having a real hard time thinking how to apply this procedure to any number of lists...
Any help would be appreciated,
Oren

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Óscar's answer is good but I would probably `reverse` the input and use `foldl` instead as `foldl` is implemented with a proper tail call.

```
(define (append* . xs)
  (foldl append null (reverse xs)))
```

Output is the same

```
(append* '(1 2) '(3) '(4 5 6) '(7 8))
=> '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
```

Comment: (I reread your answer and it doesn't suffer from the O(n²) problem I mentioned. But a naive implementation using the accumulated list as the left-hand argument to `append` would be wrong.) Here, have a +1.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young, I have read many of your contributions and highly respect your feedback. Is it possible you could detail the evaluation to better illustrate the issue? I'm still relatively new to racket.

Comment: Your answer is fine (sorry for misreading your answer in the first place). A wrong answer would be something like `(define (append* . lsts) (foldl (lambda (lst acc) (append acc lst)) '() lsts))`, which would be O(n²) (where n is the total length of all-but-the-last input list), because of the way `append` works.

Comment: Thank you for a simple solution!

Comment: @oren Huh. In doing research for an upcoming blog post to answer naomik's question, I've discovered that standard Scheme `append` is already variadic and already does what you seek. Are you sure you need to write any code at all? (Edit: Oh, I reread your question. You're implementing your _own_ `append`. Today's not a good day for my reading comprehension, it seems. :-P)

Comment: The blog post is up now: http://qr.ae/ROZpq7. I hope this explains the situation better! /cc @oren

Comment: Following your blog(which was great thanks!), and after a small testing of my own i stumbled upon something weird (maybe not weird but something i didn't except..) for the following code :   (define x '(1 2)) (define y '(3 4)) (define z (append x y) (set-car! x $) (set-car y *) you get -> (1 2 * 4) with scheme's append, and still (1 2 3 4) with the other implementation, I know that both x and y are runtime constants and when using cons im creating a copy of them, but the question is , what does chez do any different?

Answer (score 3):

We just have to repeatedly apply your `append` function, and `foldr` is the tool for the job. Try this:

```
(define (append* . lsts)
  (foldr (lambda (sublist acc)
           (append sublist acc))
         '()
         lsts))
```

For example:

```
(append* '(1 2) '(3) '(4 5 6) '(7 8))
=> '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
```